# Copy from S3 bucket in one account to S3 bucket in another account using Boto3 in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I have created a S3 bucket and created a file under my aws account. My account has trust relationship established with another account and I am able to put objects into the bucket in another account using Boto3. How can I copy objects from bucket in my account to bucket in another account using Boto3?

I see "access denied" when I use the code below -

```
source_session = boto3.Session(region_name = 'us-east-1')
    source_conn = source_session.resource('s3')
    src_conn = source_session.client('s3')
    dest_session = __aws_session(role_arn=assumed_role_arn, session_name='dest_session')
    dest_conn = dest_session.client ( 's3' )

    copy_source = { 'Bucket': bucket_name , 'Key': key_value }
    dest_conn.copy ( copy_source, dest_bucket_name , dest_key,ExtraArgs={'ServerSideEncryption':'AES256'}, SourceClient = src_conn )
```

In my case , src_conn has access to source bucket and dest_conn has access to destination bucket.

I believe the only way to achieve this by downloading and uploading the files.

**AWS Session**

```
client = boto3.client('sts')
            response = client.assume_role(RoleArn=role_arn, RoleSessionName=session_name)
            session = boto3.Session(
                aws_access_key_id=response['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
                aws_secret_access_key=response['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'],
                aws_session_token=response['Credentials']['SessionToken'])
```

Comment: Where did you get "__aws_session()"? You should be using public interfaces such as AssumeRole().

Comment: __aws_session is a function that I defined. I am assuming role in that function.

Comment: Defined where? Do you have a documentation link? Or is this something you wrote?

Comment: I wrote it and I have copied the code within that function in my post now.

Comment: Does your assumed role have permissions to access the source bucket? Using SourceClient does not give you additional permissions for the bucket copy.

Comment: No , assumed role only has access to destination bucket

Comment: I assumed sourceclient will access source bucket and assumed role will access destination bucket

Comment: That is why you are getting permission denied. Your assumed role needs permissions for the source bucket.

Comment: No, SourceClient gives your code running on your workstation the ability to  call HTTP HEAD to get the objects size, etc for display purposes. The actual copy happens with S3 so your role needs the required permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to attach a policy to the destination bucket permitting access from the account hosting the source bucket. eg. something like the following should work (although you may want to tighten up the permissions as appropriate):

`{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<source account ID>:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::dst_bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::dst_bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}`

Then your Lambda hosted in your source AWS account should have no problems writing to the bucket(s) in the destination AWS account.